# Are there any files stored on my hard drive when I am running the Live USB version of Ubuntu?

Tags: usb-installation

Are there any files stored on my hard drive when I am running the Live USB version of Ubuntu?  Where is web surfing history stored while running Live USB Ubuntu?

Comment: nothing is stored in your hard drive unless you save them... think the histry and other data are stored in your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

This depends the way you created the live USB.
If you setup persistence then data will be stored in a special file called casper-rw (for Ubuntu). Check the below link for more information:

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/faq/persistence/67-what-is-persistence